# VBA Open File From This Workbook's Folder Knowing Part of The Name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open file from the same folder as the main workbook. The problem is that the name is not permanent and just one word stays always inside the name - "NAME".

I want to use specific method with `Thisworkbook.Path` to open the xlsx file but it is not finding the workbook with the code.

that is the relavant part of code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicats()

Dim Harel As Workbook
Dim SAP As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim Found As String

Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
Found = Dir(Path & "*NAME*.xlsx")   'open SAP report
If Found <> "" Then
    Set SAP = Workbooks.Open(Path & Found)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ThisWorkbook.Path Returns the path without trailing backslash, 
try

```
Found = Dir ( Path & "\" & "*NAME*.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to Loop though all Fiels in this Folder and compare the File Names like this:

Dim StrFile As String

```
    StrFile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*" & ".xlsm")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        If StrFile Like "*Name*" Then
            MsgBox StrFile 'This will be your File

        End If
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: @ Moosli : your solution is basically what the dir (path & "\*NAME*.xlsx") is doing. It gives you the name of the first occurrence of a file ( in specified path) whose name contains NAME.

Comment: @h2so4 Yes you are right, this solution was also thought to show how you can do it, if multiple files include the "name". So you can catch all the Files.

Comment: ok if you remove the `exit do ` that is (was, I see you removed it just now) in your code.